# Render Transparent Text in a Colored Background

Tags: ios

Let say I have two UIViews:

View1:
  - bounds: 0, 0, 20, 20
  - background color: some complex background with a gradient or something

View2:
  - frame: 0, 0, 20, 20
  - background color: blue
  - **is a subview of View1** and completely covers it

Next I want to draw some text on View2(using a CATextLayer or any other way) and I want the text to be transparent so that it shows View1's background.

I've thought hard about this one but with no results. Anyone knows how to do this?

Thank you,

Antoni

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, setting the color to clear and drawing the text would result in no visible effect. But if you first use `CGContextSetBlendMode` with `kCGBlendModeCopy`, it should completely replace the (colored) pixels in View2's background with the transparent color you set when drawing the text.

Comment: Any chance of posting the code for the solution? I have the same question :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can set the textColor: to a UIColor that has an alpha < 1.0 Say 0.7.
You can use the string drawing methods from StringDrawing.h